# Seeking conceptual explanation of these nice bijections on roots of unity

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-fields

I proved the following facts by unenlightening calculations.  Since the statements are quite clean, I think there should be a conceptual explanation for them, which my proof certainly is not.

Let $q$ be a prime power, and let $\mu_{q+1}$ be the set of $(q+1)$-th roots of unity in the finite field $\mathbf{F}_{q^2}$.  If $b\in\mu_{q+1}$ and $c\in\mathbf{F}_{q^2}\setminus\mathbf{F}_q$ then
$$
x\mapsto \frac{cx-bc^q}{x-b}
$$
maps $\mu_{q+1}$ to $\mathbf{F}_q\cup\{\infty\}$.  If $b\in\mu_{q+1}$ and $d\in\mathbf{F}_{q^2}\setminus\mu_{q+1}$ then
$$
x\mapsto \frac{x-bd^q}{dx-b}
$$
maps $\mu_{q+1}$ to itself.  (It is also true that these are the only degree-one rational functions which map $\mu_{q+1}$ to either $\mathbf{F}_q\cup\{\infty\}$ or $\mu_{q+1}$, but I'm mainly interested in understanding the existence.)

I tagged this "group theory" because the first fact vaguely feels like a connection between orbits of a nonsplit torus and a split torus in $\textrm{PGL}_2(q)$.  It's tempting to identify $\mathbf{F}_{q^2}$ with $\mathbf{F}_q\times\mathbf{F}_q$, and consider the resulting action of $\textrm{GL}_2(q)$ on $\mathbf{F}_{q^2}$, but I don't see how to go further in this way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The parameter $b$ doesn't seem to be doing much: we can translate the group $\mu_{q+1}$ by any single element and in the fractions we can divide throughout on top and bottom.  So do we lose anything by only considering $b=1$?

Comment: @Marguax: good point!  So it suffices to prove the result for $b=1$.  Thanks!

Comment: In the 2nd case, using multiplicative translation by $-x \in \mu_{q+1}$ on the target, it is the same to ask for a "conceptual" proof that $f:x \mapsto ((d^q/x)-1)/(dx-1)$ is a bijection of $\mu_{q+1}$ onto itself. Clearly $f(x)=t(x)^{q-1}$ where $t(x)=dx-1$ (since $x^q=1/x$), so this map lands inside $\mu_{q+1}$. And using that $d^{q+1}\ne 1$ we see by cross-multiplying in an equality of fractions that $f$ is injective on $\mu_{q+1}$, hence bijective. Does this just recreate your argument for the 2nd case?

Comment: Likewise, for the 1st one, was your argument that raising to the $q$th-power gives the same fraction (using that $x^q = 1/x$) and that injectivity is a direct inspection?

Comment: Yes, my argument was to compare the $q$-th power of the given rational function $\ell(x)$ with either $\ell(x)$ or its reciprocal, after substituting $1/x$ for $x^q$.  It seemed more complicated at the time, since I was simultaneously proving uniqueness so I had additional coefficients involved.  I still hope there's a more high-brow way to explain what's going on, but you've convinced me that this isn't as mysterious as I had thought.

Comment: Yeah. A lot like the analogue with complex plane: $\mu_{q+1}$ is the unit circle, $\bf{F}_q$ is the real axis, $x\mapsto x^q$ is the complex conjugation that amounts to taking the reciprocal on the unit circle. I'm not sure that I've seen this before. But I have used (and seen it used by other coding theorists in need of evaluating some character sums) the mapping $x\mapsto (c+x)/(c^q+x)$ to parametrize $\mu_{q+1}\setminus\{1\}$ by elements $x\in\bf{F}_q$. Here $c\in\bf{F}_{q^2}\setminus\bf{F}_q$ is a fixed constant.

Comment: @Jyrki: thanks, I didn't realize this was known to coding theorists.  If you substitute $-c^q$ for $c$ in your expression $(c+x)/(c^q+x)$, you get the inverse of my $(cx-bc^q)/(x-b)$ when $b=1$.  Your analogy with the complex plane seems like a good way to think about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $E$ be a curve defined by a singular Weierstrass equation over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where the singularity is a node, say at the origin. Then, Silverman says (Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, page 46) that $E$ may be written as
$$
E: y^2 + A_1 xy - A_2 x^2 - x^3 = 0,
$$
where $A_1^2 + 4 A_2$ is not zero.
If the two tangent lines at the node are given by $y = a_i x$ for $i=1,2$, then by comparing coefficients we see that the slopes are roots of $t^2 + A_1 t - A_2$.

Suppose this quadratic is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then it splits in $L = \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$. According to Silverman's Prop. 2.5 on page 56 (properly adjusted to not assume algebraic closure, see Exercise 3.5 on page 105), the map $(x,y) \rightarrow (y - a_1 x)/(y - a_2 x)$ gives us an isomorphism of algebraic groups $E_{ns}(L)\cong L^\times$. Part (ii) of the exercise referenced above shows that under this isomorphism, $E_{ns}(K)$ corresponds precisely to those elements of $L^\times$ whose norm to $K$ is $1$. Now $N(x) = x\cdot x^q = x^{q+1}$, so elements of norm $1$ are precisely the $(q+1)th$ roots of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$. Since $E$ is singular with a point defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$, its non-singular part is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

So, we have a bijection between the $(q+1)th$ roots of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ and $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$ given by a linear fractional transformation.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the sort of explanation I was looking for.  Incidentally, in order that the map $(x:y:z)\mapsto(x:y)$ should give a bijection $E_{ns}(\mathbb{F}_q)\to\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$, we need the $a_i$ to be outside $\mathbb{F}_q$, or equivalently we need $A_1^2+4A_2$ to be a nonsquare in $\mathbb{F}_q$.  I think this condition is needed in order for your construction to give the desired bijection $\mu_{q+1}\to\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{F}_q)$.  Also, not surprisingly my bijections of $\mu_{q+1}$ arise by composing one of your bijections with the inverse of another.

Comment: I agree, this assumption comes into my argument when I assume the quadratic $t^2 + A_1t - A_2$ is irreducible over $F_q$.

Answer (score 9):

The question and the analog to the Cayley map in complex numbers pointed out in the comment by Jyrki Lahtonen is not only an *analog*, but in fact both are special cases of this more general observation: Let $z\mapsto\bar z$ be an involutory automorphism of a field $F$, and let $E$ be the subfield fixed by $\bar{\phantom{a}}$. Furthermore, set $S=\{z\in F\;|\;z\bar z=1\}$. Then, for $b\in S$, $c\in F\setminus E$, and $d\in F\setminus S$,
\begin{equation*}
z\mapsto \frac{cz-b\bar c}{z-b}
\end{equation*}
maps $S$ to $E\cup\{\infty\}$ and
\begin{equation*}
z\mapsto \frac{z-b\bar d}{dz-b}
\end{equation*}
maps $S$ to $S$.